# Bluetooth error on iOS, CoreBluetooth API MISUSE, & detecting bluetooth permissions

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter_blue_plus available on pub.dev, and permissions_handler for requesting the needed permissions from the user.

On Android I am seeing a PlatformException error with the code of "no_permissions"... but on iOS I am not seeing this error, instead everytime starting the app for the first time I get this error:

[CoreBluetooth] API MISUSE: <CBCentralManager: 0x283e7f160> can only accept this command while in the powered on state

To deal with this error I am just requesting the scan again. Why is this error occuring?

And how can I detect the user has denied the required permissions for my bluetooth to function?

Things I have tried:

```
void RequestPermission() async {
    PermissionStatus locationPermission = await Permission.location.request();
    PermissionStatus bleScan = await Permission.bluetoothScan.request();
    PermissionStatus bleConnect = await Permission.bluetoothConnect.request();
    if (locationPermission.isDenied || locationPermission.isPermanentlyDenied || bleScan.isDenied || bleScan.isPermanentlyDenied || bleConnect.isDenied || bleConnect.isPermanentlyDenied) {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => BluetoothDisabledView()
          )
      );
    }
  }
```

The above code sends the user to the BluetoothDisabledView all the time on iOS, without any dialogues/permission requests presented to the user. I am using this package for permissions: https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

What should I be looking for on iOS to detect if we have the required permissions?